# filemode can not be changed when checkout a new branch

Tags: c, libgit2

i'm writing a simple code to implement `git checkout branch-name`

```
git_repository *repo = NULL;
git_signature *sig;
git_checkout_options opts = GIT_CHECKOUT_OPTIONS_INIT;
opts.checkout_strategy = GIT_CHECKOUT_FORCE;

git_signature_now(&sig, "name", "email");

git_repository_open(&repo, "test");
git_repository_set_head(repo, "refs/heads/v1", sig, NULL);
git_checkout_tree(repo, NULL, &opts);

git_signature_free(sig);
git_repository_free(repo);
```

Everything works fine except filemode change.

```
$ git status
On branch v1
Your branch is up-to-date with 'sugareps/ibm_r22'.
Changes to be committed:
    modified:  include/javascript/select2/select2-spinner.gif
    modified:  include/javascript/select2/select2.png

Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:  /modules/DropDownBrowser.php


$git diff # or git diff --cached
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
```

What should I do for this? Can someone give me some suggestion.

Comment: It's possible that it's a bug in libgit2. There's [an issue in pygit2](https://github.com/libgit2/pygit2/issues/423) suggesting it doesn't work.

Comment: Coincidentally, I've just independently tripped across exactly the same problem, and your account of it is all I have found in Google so far. I can reproduce it with a very simple repo, with two commits which only differ by a filemode change. My code looks very similar to yours, and I've found no obvious workaround.  Broken in 0.21.3, 0.21.5, and 0.22.1.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://git.kaarsemaker.net/libgit2/commit/780f3e540fa6492b244ef2750a71e39407526c1e/) suggests that libgit2 takes account of `umask` when creating files or directories. This means if you want `libgit2` to be able to create files with any permissions, you will need to set your umask to 0 first.

Comment: It is not work for me, I add `umask(0)` before `git_checkout_tree`. and get the same result. But thank you for your replay :).